# Script fails to generate results

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script in python to scrape the result populated upon filling in two inputboxes `zipcode` and `distance` with `66109`,`10000`. When I try the inputs manually, the site does display results but when I try the same using the script I get nothing. The script throws no error either. What might be the issues here?

[Website link](https://www.sart.org/clinic-pages/find-a-clinic/)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sart.org/clinic-pages/find-a-clinic/'

payload = {
    'zip': '66109',
    'strdistance': '10000',
    'SelectedState': 'Select State or Region'
}

def get_clinics(link):
    session = requests.Session()   
    response = session.post(link,data=payload,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one(".clinics__search-meta").text
    print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_clinics(url)
```

I'm only after this line ***Within 10000 miles of 66109 there are 383 clinics.*** generated when the search is made.

[image: see_screnshot]

Comment: Have you tried printing out the response? If i use the website, i see there is a content length attribute in the header that gets passed, these are usually required

Comment: The leading dot `.` means it's a class. This is how selector works @stovfl.

Comment: Yep. But I could not find anything what I'm looking for @stovfl.

Comment: Response gives **empty** `<div class="clinics__search-meta"></div>`, therefore **no** `BeautifulSoup` issue.

Comment: Change ` data=payload` to ` params=payload` as the site uses `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the url and the requests method to GET and worked for me

```
 def get_clinics(link):
    session = requests.Session()   
    response = session.get(link, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    item = soup.select_one(".clinics__search-meta").text
    print(item)

url = 'https://www.sart.org/clinic-pages/find-a-clinic?zip=66109&strdistance=10000&SelectedState=Select+State+or+Region'
get_clinics(url)
```

Comment: It worked wonderfully!! However, I got confused why it worked coz when I recorded the requests using chrome dev tools, I found that the method is clearly indicated there as `post` @Juan Javier Santos Ochoa. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Include cookies is one of the main concern here. If you do it in the right way, you can get a valid response following the way you started. Here is the working code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.sart.org/clinic-pages/find-a-clinic/'

payload = {
    'zip': '66109',
    'strdistance': '10000',
    'SelectedState': 'Select State or Region'
}

def get_clinics(link):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        res = s.get(link)
        req = s.post(link,data=payload,cookies=res.cookies.get_dict())   
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        item = soup.select_one(".clinics__search-meta").get_text(strip=True)
        print(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_clinics(url)
```